# eventos en angular 9

Tags: angular9

/Tengo esta linea de código en el html situado en **index/index.component.html**

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="AuthService.logout()">Cerrar sesion</a>
```

//Este es mi auth.service.ts situado en **services**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

private URL = 'http://localhost:3000/'

constructor(
  private http: HttpClient,
  private router: Router
) { }

register(user: any){
  return this.http.post<any>(this.URL + 'registro', user)
}

start(init){
  return this.http.post<any>(this.URL + 'iniciar', init)
}

loggedin():boolean{
  return !!localStorage.getItem('token')
}

getToken(){
  return localStorage.getItem('token')
}

logout(){
  localStorage.removeItem('token');

  this.router.navigate([''])
 }

}
```

//este es el directorio de ambos archivos
[image: este es el directorio donde estan situados los archivos]

//lo que esta pasando es que quiero traer el `logout()` y usarlo en el html pero no lo reconoce

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es injectar el servicio en su componente y desde ahi va a tener accesso a los metodos

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../service/auth.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './index.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./index.component.scss']
})
export class IndexComponent {

    constructor(private auth: AuthService ) {          
    }

    register(user: any){
         auth.register(user);
    }

   start(init){
      auth.start(init);
    }

   loggedin():boolean{
     auth.loggedin();
   }

   getToken(){
     auth.getToken();
   }

  logout(){
    auth.logout();
  }

}
```

Nota: Esta implementacion del componente es simple, pero aqui van validaciones y recuerde que la respuesta de este servicio son Observables que deben ser resueltos.

finalmente su html debe ser algo como esto:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Cerrar sesion</a>
```

Espero le sea util esta solucion.